# How do I add a Logo the the top left of the Navigation Bar?

Tags: html, css

Right now the Logo image is included in the HTML code at line 17, it is titled Studio Ghibli Logo. How can I move this so it could be in the top left of the navbar [ref image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YkFP.jpg)

Is there a better way to get code the navbar vs the code I included? Feel free to suggest tips, tools, or references.

I include a snippet of my code.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #52b2cf;
}

li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: Left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #fffbeb;
  color: #7b81ab;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #fff1cc;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d8d5f2;
}

body {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
}

img {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

h1 {
  color: darkslateblue;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: lightcoral;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: darkslateblue;
}

img {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
<title>Spirited Away Fansite</title>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="FilmPlot.html">Film Plot</a></li>
  <li><a href="cast.html">Cast</a></li>
  <li><a href="prod.html">Production</a></li>
  <li><a href="recept.html">Reception</a></li>
</ul>

<body>
  <img src="images/Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg.png" alt="Studio Ghibli Logo" width="200" height="90">
  <h1> 千と千尋の神隠し ∘ Spirited Away </h1>
  <p> This is a fansite for the Studio Ghibli Film Spirited Away </p>
  <h2> ABOUT </h2>
  <p>
    Spirited Away (Japanese: 千と千尋の神隠し, Hepburn: Sen to Chihiro no Kamikakushi, 'Sen and Chihiro's Spiriting Away') is a 2001 Japanese animated fantasy film written and directed by Hayao Miyazaki, animated by Studio Ghibli for Tokuma Shoten, Nippon Television
    Network, Dentsu, Buena Vista Home Entertainment, Tohokushinsha Film, and Mitsubishi. Spirited Away tells the story of Chihiro Ogino (Hiiragi), a ten-year-old girl who, while moving to a new neighborhood, enters the world of Kami (spirits of Japanese
    Shinto folklore).<br>
  </p>
  <img src=images/Spirited_Away_Japanese_poster.png alt="Spirited Away Movie Poster" width="290" height="400"> <img src="images/hayaomiya.jpg" alt="Hayao Miyazaki at desk" width="290" height="400">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would nest the `ul` and the image in `nav` and call it `navbar`. Then you can set that nav to `display: flex;` with `justify-content: space-between;`. Lastly, just move the background color from the ul to the new `div`.

I also went through and cleaned up the `ul` and the `li`, `a`'s styles to make a bit more responsive. Whether you want to use those is completely up to you.

Side note - the `body` element is supposed to contain all page elements including nav `ul`'s.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #52b2cf;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #52b2cf;
}


li a {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #fffbeb;
  color: #7b81ab;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #fff1cc;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d8d5f2;
}

body {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: darkslateblue;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: lightcoral;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: darkslateblue;
}

body>.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
<title>Spirited Away Fansite</title>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <img src="https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/217/740/HD-wallpaper-studio-ghibli-logo-black-and-white-studio-ghibli-totoro-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Studio Ghibli Logo" width="50" height="50" class="logo">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="FilmPlot.html">Film Plot</a></li>
      <li><a href="cast.html">Cast</a></li>
      <li><a href="prod.html">Production</a></li>
      <li><a href="recept.html">Reception</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1> 千と千尋の神隠し ∘ Spirited Away </h1>
  <p> This is a fansite for the Studio Ghibli Film Spirited Away </p>
  <h2> ABOUT </h2>
  <p>
    Spirited Away (Japanese: 千と千尋の神隠し, Hepburn: Sen to Chihiro no Kamikakushi, 'Sen and Chihiro's Spiriting Away') is a 2001 Japanese animated fantasy film written and directed by Hayao Miyazaki, animated by Studio Ghibli for Tokuma Shoten, Nippon Television
    Network, Dentsu, Buena Vista Home Entertainment, Tohokushinsha Film, and Mitsubishi. Spirited Away tells the story of Chihiro Ogino (Hiiragi), a ten-year-old girl who, while moving to a new neighborhood, enters the world of Kami (spirits of Japanese
    Shinto folklore).<br>
  </p>
  <img src=images/Spirited_Away_Japanese_poster.png alt="Spirited Away Movie Poster" width="290" height="400"> <img src="images/hayaomiya.jpg" alt="Hayao Miyazaki at desk" width="290" height="400">

</body>
```

Comment: if you have a navbar, you should use the semantic `<nav>` tag instead of `div class="navbar">` which greatly icnreases the accessibility with screen-readers.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely put the `ul` into the `body` (every HTML element you display on the page has to go in the `body`). And then there is a `nav` tag which you could use:

```
<nav>
    <img src="https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/217/740/HD-wallpaper-studio-ghibli-logo-black-and-white-studio-ghibli-totoro-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Studio Ghibli Logo" width="50" height="50">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="FilmPlot.html">Film Plot</a></li>
      <li><a href="cast.html">Cast</a></li>
      <li><a href="prod.html">Production</a></li>
      <li><a href="recept.html">Reception</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to give you more tips on your navbar but it is not clear how you want it to look like.

Comment: semantically speaking you should not put the image in the `<nav>` tag as it is not a anavigation element. You should wrap the `nav>` inside a `<header>` tag and incldue the image to that element.

Comment: I would disagree here as logo image usually is a navigation element which leads to home page so technically it is part of the navbar.. of course it needs to be wrapped in an a tag but I didn't want to overcomplicate things for OP for start

Answer (score 0):

you want to just take your logo image and make it a list item in your nav.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #52b2cf;
}

li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: Left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #fffbeb;
  color: #7b81ab;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #fff1cc;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d8d5f2;
}

body {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
}

img {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

h1 {
  color: darkslateblue;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: lightcoral;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
<title>Spirited Away Fansite</title>
<ul>
  <li><img src="images/Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg.png" alt="Studio Ghibli Logo" width="200" height="90"></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="FilmPlot.html">Film Plot</a></li>
  <li><a href="cast.html">Cast</a></li>
  <li><a href="prod.html">Production</a></li>
  <li><a href="recept.html">Reception</a></li>
</ul>
<body>
  <h1> 千と千尋の神隠し ∘ Spirited Away </h1>
  <p> This is a fansite for the Studio Ghibli Film Spirited Away </p>
  <h2> ABOUT </h2>
  <p>
    Spirited Away (Japanese: 千と千尋の神隠し, Hepburn: Sen to Chihiro no Kamikakushi, 'Sen and Chihiro's Spiriting Away') is a 2001 Japanese animated fantasy film written and directed by Hayao Miyazaki, animated by Studio Ghibli for Tokuma Shoten, Nippon Television
    Network, Dentsu, Buena Vista Home Entertainment, Tohokushinsha Film, and Mitsubishi. Spirited Away tells the story of Chihiro Ogino (Hiiragi), a ten-year-old girl who, while moving to a new neighborhood, enters the world of Kami (spirits of Japanese
    Shinto folklore).<br>
  </p>
  <img src=images/Spirited_Away_Japanese_poster.png alt="Spirited Away Movie Poster" width="290" height="400"> <img src="images/hayaomiya.jpg" alt="Hayao Miyazaki at desk" width="290" height="400">
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could Bootstrap for this or set up a CSS grid so that you can then set the dive to a place on the page then just left justify the content.

Comment: Answer is to broad for SO. You should never purelybase an answer on recommending to use a framework. Beside that, your answer could have been rgeatly improved by a workign snippet showing an example of your solution. As of now your answer is merely a hint into a direction (IMHO a wrong direction). You may do that within the comment section (but even then recommending a framework is in most cases not appropiate as hint).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).